# jquery create chainable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious how to create a chainable function that would inherit the document object from the previous function

Example

```
var d = function(){
   return $(document).on("click", ".s", function(){
       ..Some stuff
   });
}, //Returns the document object
c = function(){
    d().on("click", ".dd", function(){ //Chained from above
       ..Some more stuff
    });
};
```

In the example i chained the d function in the c function. However, i am curious if it is possible to pass the $(document) object so i could essentially pass it on just like:

```
 $(document).toggleClass("hello").addClass("bye").prop("disabled", true) //Etc..
```

Instead i would want to my own functions which just need the document object passed into them. I realize i could do:

```
var function1 = function($document){
    $document.on("click", ".dd", function(){ //Chained from above
       ..Some more stuff
    });
},
function2 = function($document){
    $document.on("click", ".ddss", function(){ 
       ..Some other stuff
    });
};

var $d = $(document);

function1($d);
function2($d);
```

I would prefer not to cache the document object like this and learn how to pass the document into the function do i could simply chain them

Example

```
var d = function(){
   return $(document).on("click", ".abc", function(){
    //Do stuff
  });
},
ff = function(){
    //i want the document from function d
}
```

And to use them

```
d().ff().on("click", "button", function(){....
```

Comment: But why ? .........

Comment: i have duplicate code attached to the document element that i want to eliminate, put into a function and then call the function

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You should show the code you want to reduce...